# How to get value of the value in Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Example of my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <latest>http://repo1.com:port/nexus</latest>
    <freeze>http://repo2.com:port/nexus</freeze>

    <repo>${latest}</repo>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Default-repo</id>
        <url>${repo}</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I'd like to pass command line parameter like `mvn clean package -Drepo=latest`.

But, is there a way to get value of the value in the pom ? `<url>${${repo}}</url>` does not work.

I do not want to use profiles in this case.

Comment: Better use a repository manager instead.

Comment: You'll need to use profiles or pass the whole url as the parameter. Why don't you want to use profiles? This use case is the exact reason why profiles exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven is not designed to do that. That's better to use available solutions like repository manager or profiles